# Set Value of Multiple Form Fields in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to set the result (value) of multiple form fields as one variable rather than me entering a line for each form field and setting the value with the same variable over and over? Here's what I'm doing:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text31").Result = lender
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text35").Result = lender
ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text46").Result = lender
```

All these form fields will read the same value of the variable but the fields are in different parts of my word document.

I have some pages in the document where I am bringing in an excel CSV and some of the word pages I've prepared have the same data so that's the reason for the question. If this is not possible, is there a way to link one form field's value to another in word?

Comment: Try iteration between all of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testFormFieldsResult()
   Dim ff As FormField, lender as string
   lender = "Another Test..."
   For Each ff In ActiveDocument.FormFields
        If ff.Type = wdFieldFormTextInput Then
            Select Case Right(ff.Name, 2)
                Case 31, 35, 46 'add whatever necessary
                    ff.Result = lender 
                Case 60, 61
                    'fill with something else
            End Select
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I apologize but I should have been more detailed in my question. I have other form fields that should have other values. So, for instance, 4 of the form fields might be the variable lender, and these form fields are labeled differently ("Text 31", "Text35 " and "Text46") but then I might have 5 other formfields that should be another variable value.

Comment: @A Kapadia: Then, a pattern of their name must be used. If I would consider that the involved form fields to be filled name would be something like "Text" followed by 31, 35, 46 and something else only you know, will it be OK?

Comment: @A Kapadia: Adapted the code to fill the text only in the form fields having a specific name ending...

Comment: @A Kapadia: Did you find time to check the above updated code? If yes, doesn't it do what you need?

Comment: @A Kapadia: Glad I could help! But, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, if somebody else search for a similar issue will know that the code works...